# Recursive sed shell function doesn't do anything

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Referring to other Q/As on SO, I added the following to my .bashrc:

```
function findandreplace {
    find . -type f -name "$1" -not -path "*/.git/*" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/$2/$3/g'
}
```

Oddly, it doesn't do anything. When I change it to:

```
function findandreplace {
    echo "find . -type f -name \"$1\" -not -path \"*/.git/*\" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/$2/$3/g'"
}
```

I get

```
$ findandreplace "*.cpp" "A.cpp" "B.cpp"
find . -type f -name "*.cpp" -not -path "*/.git/*" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/A.cpp/B.cpp/g'
```

as expected. Copy-pasting that command then performs the expected operation.

What's wrong with my initial function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `'s/$2/$3/g'` part doesn't make sense; single-quotes prevent parameter-expansion, so your actual sed script is `s/$2/$3/g` (dollar signs and all) rather than `s/A.cpp/B.cpp/g`. Since `$` in a regex means "end-of-string" (or sometimes "end-of-line"), `$2` will never match anything.

To fix this, you can use double-quotes instead:

```
function findandreplace {
    find . -type f -name "$1" -not -path "*/.git/*" -print0 \
    | xargs -0 sed -i "s/$2/$3/g"
}
```

with the caveat that this will misbehave if `$2` or `$3` contains slashes. (*Edited to add:*) To fix that, you can ask Bash to replace `/` with `\/` in those parameters, though it's pretty ugly:

```
function findandreplace {
    find . -type f -name "$1" -not -path "*/.git/*" -print0 \
    | xargs -0 sed -i "s/${2//\//\/}/${3//\//\/}/g"
}
```

Comment: Is there a possibility not to exclude one sign from the expanded sed command (like `/` in this example)?

Comment: But the misbehaving can be mitigated by escaping those slashes?

Comment: @brandones: Yes. I've updated my answer to add a version that does that. It looks ridiculous as heck, though. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Because of use of single quotes:

```
sed -i 's/$2/$3/g'
```

won't work since shell won't expand these variables. Use sed like this:

```
sed -i "s/$2/$3/g"
```